# Remove Push Notif Listener using class/controller

Tags: pushtopic

Is there a way to remove notification listener using the class/controller of my VF page?

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_console/Content/sforce_api_console_removepushnotificationlistener.htm

In this link, is it only working when you're using a standard controller? Cause this one isn't working when i tried it.